# rx java как синхронизировать последовательный вызов одного метода

Tags: java, rxjava

Есть метод контроллера addItem(), который используется для сохранения элемента, на каждый новый элемент подписывается Subscriber:

```
public void addItem(String item){
    someService.save(item);
    PublishSubject<String> subject = PublishSubject.create();
    subject.subscribeOn(Schedulers.trampoline()).subscribe(simpleObserver);
    subject.onNext(item);
    log.info("Save item - " + item);
}
```

и есть SimpleObserver

```
    public class SimpleObserver extends Subscriber<String> {

    @Override
    public void onCompleted() {
        log.info("onCompleted...");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
        log.info("onError Subscriber...");
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(String s) {
        log.info("After subscribe " + s");
    }
}
```

при последовательном вызове

```
addItem1("Item1");
addItem1("Item2");
addItem1("Item3");
addItem1("Item4");
```

получается результат

```
After subscribe Item1
Save item - Item1
After subscribe Item2
Save item - Item2
After subscribe Item3
Save item - Item3
After subscribe Item4
Save item - Item4
```

Как сделать чтоб сначала выполнились все someService.save(item); в mainThread, а потом последовательно в отдельном ThreadPool все onNext() simpleObserver-a, т.е. результат должен быть:

```
Save item - Item1
Save item - Item2
Save item - Item3
Save item - Item4 //все save в mainThread
After subscribe Item1
After subscribe Item2
After subscribe Item3
After subscribe Item4 //все After subscribe в одном отдельном пуле потоков последовательно
```

Comment: Не знаю как вы используете код, но почему бы не вызвать все onNext последовательно отдельным методом в нужный момент? Т.е. сначала подписываете всех кого надо, делаете остальную работу, а потом вызываете отдельно метод с черезой onNext. Вы же не ожидаете что какой-то магией код поймёт сам что addItem1 был вызван последний раз и теперь можно что-то делать?

Comment: на самом деле каждый onNext() должен вызываться отдельно, т.к метод addItem() вызывается в RestControllere, поэтому мне нужно придумать как каждый Item забить в очередь и обработать в одном ThreadPool

Comment: Ну так я вроде это и предлагаю... Вызывайте их отдельно... Помещайте данные для них в сисок и в к-л момент вызовите onNext с ними....

Comment: К сожалению надо каждый onNext() отдельно...То есть потом вызвать один метод с чередой onNext() не подходит...

Comment: В этом случае ваш вопрос становится совсем непонятным и скорее всего решения просто не существует, ибо невозможно узнать когда вы закончите вызывать addItem чтобы начать вызывать onNext. В принципе невозможно.

Comment: Интересно, а где на практике нужна подобная задача?

Comment: на практике это Веб-проект(сайт), есть рестконтроллер с addItem(), и нужно чтоб при создании нового Item запускался сторонний сервис, который я не хочу в жесткую прописывать в контроллере(или инжектить) и поэтому подписал на появление каждого нового Itema Subscriber, в котором и вызываю этот сервис...

Comment: ЮрийСПб , по-моему впринципе возможно...исхожу из того, что если сделать такой код: subject.observeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).subscribe(simpleObserver); то получается вывод на SimpleObserver отдельно в каждом потоке...Осталось сделать это в отдельном ThreadPool...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сам отвечу на свой вопрос:
Нужно было использовать ExecutorService и добавить:

```
private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1, new ThreadFactoryBuilder().setNameFormat("SubscribeOn-%d").build());
```

тогда метод будет выглядеть так:

```
public void addItem1(String item){
    someService.save(item);
    PublishSubject<String> subject = PublishSubject.create();
    subject.observeOn(Schedulers.from(executor)).subscribe(simpleObserver);
    subject.onNext(item);
    log.info("Save item - " + item + Thread.currentThread());
}
```

и результат:

```
Save item - Item1 Thread[main,5,main]
Save item - Item2 Thread[main,5,main]
Save item - Item3 Thread[main,5,main]
Save item - Item4 Thread[main,5,main]
After subscribe Item1 Thread[SubscribeOn-0,5,main]
After subscribe Item2 Thread[SubscribeOn-0,5,main]
After subscribe Item3 Thread[SubscribeOn-0,5,main]
After subscribe Item4 Thread[SubscribeOn-0,5,main]
```